# Heisenberg relation and continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

**Problem**: let $P, Q \colon V \to V$ be linear functions on normed vector space $V$. Assume that they satisfy $PQ - QP = \textrm{id}$. Both $P$ and $Q$ can't be continuous.

**What have I tried so far**: by simple induction I am able to show that $PQ^n - Q^nP=  nQ^{n-1}$. The only solution that I know states that if $P,Q$ were continuous then $\|\color{blue}{Q^n}\| = 0$for sufficiently large values of $n$. Why?

Comment: Is the norm multiplicative?

Comment: The norm used here is the operator norm, $\|A\| = \sup\{ \|Ax\| :  x \in V, \|x\|\le 1\}$ and as far as I know, it's not multiplicative: $\|AB\| \le \|A\|\|B\|$ (if $A, B$ are continuous, linear).

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: I meant sub multiplicative, so you have answered my second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ and $Q$ are bounded, then
\begin{align}
        n\|Q^{n-1}\| = \|nQ^{n-1}\| &  = \|PQ^{n}-Q^{n}P\| \\
            & \le \|P\|\|Q^{n}\|+\|Q^{n}\|\|P\| \\
            &  = 2\|P\|\|Q^{n}\| \\
            &  \le 2\|P\|\|Q\|\|Q^{n-1}\|.
\end{align}
If $\|Q^{n-1}\| \ne 0$, then
$$
           n \le 2\|P\|\|Q\|.
$$
This is impossible for large enough $n$, which means that $Q^{n-1}=0$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: So $\|Q^n\| = 0$ for large $n$ and therefore $Q$ maps everything to $0$. The conclusion: $PQ - QP$ can't be equal to $\textrm{id}$, right?

Comment: @LeonAragones : I'll be explicit. If $Q^{n}=0$, then $Q^{n-1}=0$ because $nQ^{n-1}=PQ^{n}-Q^{n}P$. Eventually, $Q=0$, which contradicts $I=PQ-QP$.